# How do I drop custom types using SQLAlchemy + PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a script which cleans the database, and this is widely used in our tests.

First, we tried to use SQLAlchemy Metadata.drop_all() thing, but it didn't resolve some foreign keys on deletion, which caused errors. Then, I found [this script](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/DropEverything) from @zzzeek, which does almost the same, but in a "smart" way. It handles all the issues with foreign keys, but now there are several issues regarding changed custom types (ENUMs). The question is, how can I drop them all them using SQLAlchemy? Execute DROP TYPE by hand only?

Tables in database are created with Alembic, and even while script above deletes all tables successfully, some custom ENUMs are still there and everything fails on attempt to recreate them.

Recreating the whole database is not a preferred solution, because default DB user for application shouldn't normally have rights to create databases.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your Metadata instance fully describes all the tables?

Try:

```
Metadata.reflect()
Metadata.drop_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient question, but it's still possible to come across this problem if `create_type=False` is on any `postgresql.ENUM` definitions.

Per the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=create_type#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM.params.create_type) on `create_type`,

> When False, no check will be performed and no CREATE TYPE or DROP TYPE is emitted, unless ENUM.create() or ENUM.drop() are called directly.

That means when running tests, while there may be a setup & teardown with `create_all()` and `drop_all()`, neither will affect custom enum types.

The solution is simply to remove `create_type=False`, since `True` is the default. Then all custom types will be created at the beginning of testing and dropped at the end, resulting in a perfectly clean test database.